# How to find the first number in a string and print everything before it using AWK

Tags: awk

I have an input file containing thousands of incodes and this is a sample of it:

```
BS11,A
BS11,A
G34 ,B 
G4  ,B
```

I want to write an awk script that will search $1 and find the first occurrance of a number <0,9> then delete everything in $1 after it. So my output would be:

```
BS,A
BS,A
G,B
G,B
```

How would I manage to do this in AWK? I can't use anything else but awk.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/[0-9].*/,"",$1)}1' file
BS,A
BS,A
G,B 
G,B
```

The above `sub()` function will remove all the characters from the first number only in the first column (comma separated).